# absolutely positioned div inside relatively positionsed div is not moving

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On my website I have 2 col-xs-6 inside a row. Both columns have an image in each and I want to add text over the top that will move when they do due to img-responsive, however the text doesn't seem to sit in the div but instead on top of it, heres a snip of the code http://www.bootply.com/zVc28CKWFW

Edit: this is not my website but a small snippet of it hence the single col-xs-6

Edit 2: I want my text to stay centered on top of the image when the image is resized, see http://www.triplagent.com/ for a working example, when the browser is resized the images resize as well as the image stays centered on the image and moves with it, this is what I want to achieve.

Comment: You need to explain yourself better. As it stands it's not clear what behaviour you want, and what you're currently getting. Additionally, your Bootply only contains one `.col-xs-6` and a broken image which doesn't demonstrate your problem. Please update your Bootply and edit the code into your question when you're done

Comment: I said on my website, this is not my website hence 'snip' of the code. The image is 'broken' because I can't link images I have saved on my desktop to bootply (as far as I know) so if I were to do that it would always be broken hence I used a random one off the internet. Secondly, I said I want to add text on top of the image so that it moves when the image is resized due to browser resizing hence: img-responsive. The behavior I'm currently getting as I said, is that the 'text doesn't seem to sit in the div but instead on top of it' and therefore does not move with the image it is inside.

Comment: tldr; want text to move when image is resized, text does not do this and instead stays on the same spot on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your h2 tag is fine, the reason it's not sitting flush with the top of the container is because it's inheriting the browser default margin/padding. If you override these it will sit flush:

http://www.bootply.com/tBlXOzGBde

**UPDATE:**

http://www.bootply.com/wgihndvcP1

Comment: The problem is that when I downsize the window the text remains stationary and doesn't stay with the image when it reduces size ,for example, http://www.bootply.com/fz1q0fMtM0 if you change the size of your window, the box will be fluid and become smaller however the text doesn't follow and appears fixed

Comment: The h2 is contained by the div not the image. The text will remain stationary as you have it positioned absolutely.

Comment: What behaviour do you want the text to have? Should it shift vertically or horizontally on resize?

Comment: But since the div is positioned relatively, shouldn't the text follow as it is absolute?

Comment: I want the text to remain in the center of the image, so basically shift vertically and horizontally according to how the image shifts

Comment: http://www.triplagent.com/ perfect example of what I want to achieve, if you scroll down to the locations and resize the window, the text remains on the same spot of the image as it gets resized

Comment: See my update, is this what you mean?

Comment: Yep thats it :) I'll try implementing it onto my website and see how it goes

Comment: Good to hear. Just remember h2 is a block element so will fill up the width of the screen and alignment is inherited so you have to use `text-align:center`

Comment: If your problem is solved, update the question accordingly.

Comment: upon trying to put it into my website, instead of the text applying to the div I put it inside of it is applying to a div way above it near the header, screenshots: https://imgur.com/9xZe1sf,rWWeerj#0

Comment: What's the problem? You don't see the text or the text is positioned incorrectly?

Comment: It isn't positioned correctly, on the screen shots it should be on the image where I have circled in black but instead it is in the center of a div that I have below my header

Comment: So the text is positioned below your image and you want it to sit on top of?

Comment: The text is positioned on top of a whole other div, I'm trying to place it on an image like you did previously that is near the footer but its going on top of the wrong image for some reason

Comment: This? http://www.bootply.com/GpdHXGMMot

Comment: Assuming this is my website : http://www.bootply.com/WOiTlp2vbK the "Abu Dhabi" sits on the "Content" part instead of the image below it (this doesn't happen here but it is what is happening on my website for some reason :( )

Comment: But it doesn't in the example you're providing. Can you provide the actual code which is causing the issue please?

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/SxyMFyUjG8 I was hesitant because I'm unsure of how to link images that I get from my desktop so they appear as broken links and the issue can't really be shown

Comment: Looks fine to me? http://www.bootply.com/6XSQrQgnaH

Comment: It seems to work fine of bootply :/ but not on my website.. it might be one of the images im using or something causing the problem